# Possible to hide parts of the slug from get_template_directory_uri and bloginfo('template_directory')

Tags: permalinks, links, slug

At the moment i am running and building a wp site on a local install with mamp. Additionally i have moved the wp files from the root directory to a folder.

i've included files then e.g. with

```
<?php $url = get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
```

or

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://localhost:8888/myhomepage/vHGNd37wDb/wp-content/themes/mytheme/touchicon.png">
```

but if i take a look at the resulting html source of the latter i get

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://localhost:8888/myhomepage/vHGNd37wDb/wp-content/themes/mytheme/touchicon.png">
```

somehow i hoped the wp-content wouldn't show up and also the move of the wp files from the root to the vHGNd37wDb folder seems useless if that directory name is visible to everybody. :/ Is the latter cuz i am on a local install right now? So would it be possible to prevent both from showing up? best regards ralf

Comment: So, you are trying to "hide" WordPress?

Comment: Honestly speaking the length and the contained elements of the href link just puzzled me and still do. Especially the former where i've moved the wp install to the custom subdirectory (vHGNd37wDb). If that is shown in the link the move was more or less useless. I thought only the site adress would be shown instead of the wordpress adress. and on a sidenote i also noticed that each absolute link contains the wp-content. But for that i've found an url rewrite: http://www.kevinleary.net/hide-site-is-using-wordpress/  . But about the vHGNd37wDb folder i am still confused how to solve :(

Comment: The main motivation were security concerns which leads to hiding to some extent